# count number of times a column value contains elements in a list in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set like this
list = {'AGB', 'YTE', 'ENN', 'TAP', 'XAL', 'MUI'}

and a dataframe like this

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ENN,JAX,ATL,ERT,CMH,RSW,TAP,ABQ,ENN | 45 | Three |
| TUY,XAL,MUI,AUS,OPP,YTE,ERT | 32 | Three |

I would like to count how many times ColA's value has elements in the set in ColD and ColE, ColD for unique and ColD for all occurrences. So far, I have been using
df['ColD'] = df['ColA'].apply(lambda x:sum(i in list for i in x)), but no success, would very appreciate if someone can help solve the issue. Thank you.

| ColA | ColD | ColE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **ENN**,JAX,ATL,ERT,CMH,RSW,**TAP**,ABQ,**ENN** | 2 | 3 |
| TUY,**XAL**,**MUI**,AUS,OPP,**YTE**,ERT | 3 | 3 |

Comment: There may be a better way to address this if those are in an RDB (and you can change the schema). But that would be more of a review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `pd.Series.str.count`

we do `'|'.join(s)` to create a string from your set which creates the following regex pattern `'AGB|ENN|YTE|XAL|TAP|MUI'` the pipe delimiter is the `OR` operator in regex, which is what `str.count` uses. So we are essentially saying count the number of times `AGB OR ENN OR ... MUI` is in `df['ColA']`

To get the unique count we need to split the string into a list and get the unique values before using str.count

I should note that this regex `'AGB|YTE...'`, this will count any occurrence so for example `ENNN` would be counted.

```
s = {'AGB', 'YTE', 'ENN', 'TAP', 'XAL', 'MUI'}

df['D'] = df['ColA'].str.split(',').agg(set).astype(str).str.count('|'.join(s))
df['E'] = df['ColA'].str.count('|'.join(s))

                                  ColA  ColB   ColC  D  E
0  ENN,JAX,ATL,ERT,CMH,RSW,TAP,ABQ,ENN    45  Three  2  3
1          TUY,XAL,MUI,AUS,OPP,YTE,ERT    32  Three  3  3
```

Comment: Is there a way in pandas to use set intersection instead of str.count?

Comment: Beautiful but can you explain me how it works? I don't understand :-) +1

Comment: Oh, `str.count` use regex! I didn't know that! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can split your string and explode to get one word per row then check if match to the list/set. Finally, group by level then aggregate with nunique (count one occurrence) and size (count all occurrence):

```
s = {'AGB', 'YTE', 'ENN', 'TAP', 'XAL', 'MUI'}

out = (df.join(df['ColA'].str.split(',').explode()
                         .loc[lambda x: x.isin(s)]
                         .groupby(level=0)
                         .agg(ColD='nunique', ColE='size')))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                                  ColA  ColB   ColC  ColD  ColE
0  ENN,JAX,ATL,ERT,CMH,RSW,TAP,ABQ,ENN    45  Three     2     3
1          TUY,XAL,MUI,AUS,OPP,YTE,ERT    32  Three     3     3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function and find elements that exists in desired `lst` and return count and count_unique like the below:

```
st = {'AGB', 'YTE', 'ENN', 'TAP', 'XAL', 'MUI'}

def count_items(x):
    lst = [item for item in x.split(',') if item in st]
    return len(set(lst)), len(lst)

df[['ColD', 'ColE']] = df['ColA'].apply(count_items)
print(df)
```

---

```
                                  ColA  ColB   ColC  ColD  ColE
0  ENN,JAX,ATL,ERT,CMH,RSW,TAP,ABQ,ENN    45  Three     2     3
1          TUY,XAL,MUI,AUS,OPP,YTE,ERT    32  Three     3     3
```